# Python tuples as keys and objects as values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

My requirement is to have collection of device objects ( having capacity, manufacturer, bandwidth, cost, etc as features). I need to be able to find the device with maximum capacity. But since there could be multiple devices with same capacity from same or different manufacturer I can not use capacity as the key.

I thought of having tuple of capacity and model no as key but then I choose devices based on their capacities and not their model no.

```
        class device:



              def __init__(self):
                    self.manufacturer       =     ""
                    self.purchasecost       =     ""
                    self.capacity           =     ""      # TB
                    self.power              =     ""      # KWH
                    self.bandwidth          =     ""      # MBPS
                    self.fail_rate          =     ""
                    self.powered_on         =     ""      # %
                    self.lIOPS              =     ""                
                    self.device_type        =     ""
                    self.moveincost         =     ""      # % of purchasecost
                    self.moveoutcost        =     ""      # % of purchasecost
                    self.datacentercost     =     ""
                    self.servicelife        =     ""
                    self.model              =     ""
                    pass

              def setparam(self, device_param):
                    self.manufacturer =     device_param["manufacturer"]
                    self.purchasecost =     device_param["purchasecost"]
                    self.capacity     =     device_param["capacity"]    # TB
                    self.power        =     device_param["power"]       # KWH
                    self.bandwidth    =     device_param["bandwidth"]   # MBPS
                    self.fail_rate    =     device_param["fail_rate"]
                    self.powered_on   =     device_param["powered_on"]  # %
                    self.lIOPS        =     device_param["IOPS"]                
                    self.device_type  =     device_param["device_type"]
                    self.moveincost   =     device_param["moveincost"]  # % of purchasecost
                    self.moveoutcost  =     device_param["moveoutcost"] # % of purchasecost
                    self.datacentercost =   device_param["datacentercost"]
                    self.servicelife  =     device_param["servicelife"]
                    self.model        =     device_param["model"]
```

In a different class I am creating objects and using them.

```
             def available_devices(self):
                 hdd1 = self.createdisk1()
                 hdd2 = self.createdisk2()
                 ssd1 = self.createSSD1()
                 self.availabledevices[hdd1.model]=hdd1
                 print ( "Added HDD1 "+str(self.availabledevices[hdd1.model]))
                 self.availabledevices[hdd2.model]=hdd2  
                 print ( "Added HDD2 "+str(self.availabledevices[hdd2.model]))

                 self.availabledevices[ssd1.model]=ssd1

            def get_highest_capacity_device(self):   
                 sorted_capacities = sorted(self.availabledevices.iterkeys())
                 highest_capacity =  sorted_capacities[len(sorted_capacities) -1]
                 highest_capacity_device = self.availabledevices[highest_capacity]
                 return highest_capacity_device
```

This code currently use capacity as the key but it obviously does not work when there are multiple devices with same capacity. My question is what should I use as key so that 
- I can sort my devices based on their capacities 
- I can get all devices having a certain capacity

Comment: Why do you need a unique key for sorting? It looks like a design flaw to me. And why do you even want to sort it? Isn't simple max-search sufficient?

Comment: "This code currently use capacity as the key but it obviously does not work when there are multiple devices with same capacity" - are you sure? The sort should work just fine.

Comment: If you're talking about dict keys rather than sort keys, why not just have the value be a list of all devices with that capacity?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use a dictionary anyway? There is no benefit in contrast to a simple list:

```
availabledevices = [ hdd1, hdd2, ssd ]
highest_capacity_device = max(availabledevices, key=lambda x: x.capacity)
```